# How to display products uploaded by a particular user?

Tags: drupal, drupal-commerce

I am using a custom drupal setup with commerce installed, i.e. not commerce kickstart. I need a way to display products uploaded by a particular user. E.g. a visitor can click on the author name and it will bring him to the page where all the products created by the particular user will be displayed, I believe this can be done via views and tokens but I do not know the specifics. Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a custom view. Add a new **relationship** (click 'Advanced' to display advanced options) to the Content: Author. Once you have done that, edit the URL and add % somewhere:

URL: www.mysitename.com/products-by-author/%

Add a **contextual filter** (again, in 'Advanced') to link the % parameter to User: name (using the relatonship previously established)

This way, when you visit www.mysitename.com/products-by-author/john you will get all those products uploaded by John.